# How can I create a polymorphic tree/graph using Rc?

Tags: rust, tree, polymorphism

I have a polymorphic, reference counted tree structure in C++:

```cpp
struct Node {
  std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Node>> children;
};
```

Each node of the tree might have its own data and its own implementations. To illustrating the idea:

```cpp
struct Named : public Node {
  std::string name;
};

Node root;
int main() {
  root.children.push_back(std::shared_ptr(new Named{"Hello World"}));
}
```

Circular references are solved by `std::weak_ptr<T>`.

I tried the following in Rust:

```rs
use rc::{Rc, RefCell};

struct Node {
    children: Vec<Rc<RefCell<Node>>>,
}
```

How I would make the tree structure polymorphic at this point? As far as I know, I can only inherit traits from traits.

My best guess is to use some kind of trait that conforms to the tree-like structure, but I find it tedious to make each implementing struct a children vector. This code illustrates the idea; I have not tested it and I'm not sure if it has any errors:

```rs
trait TreeLike {
    fn get_children(&mut self) -> &mut Vec<Rc<RefCell<dyn TreeLike>>>;
}

struct A {
    children: Vec<Rc<RefCell<TreeLike>>>,
}

impl TreeLike for A {
    fn get_children(&mut self) -> &mut Vec<Rc<RefCell<dyn TreeLike>>> {
        return children;
    }
}

struct A {
    children: Vec<Rc<RefCell<TreeLike>>>,
}

impl TreeLike for B {
    fn get_children(&mut self) -> &mut Vec<Rc<RefCell<dyn TreeLike>>> {
        return children;
    }
}
```

I'm not even sure if you can use traits to own the data at this point. This also adds unnecessary virtual dispatches that are solved by direct data access in C++.

Comment: Why don't you separate the Node and its Data ? You could have a simple generics Node, and a trait only for the contained leaf value. I may miss the point  if you're just trying to have a completely generic graph or tree structure but in this case you may look at the existing crates like petagraph

Comment: I don't know C++ very well, so I'm curious: presumably, given a `Node`, it's impossible to determine whether it is a `Named` or not?  So casting it as such and accessing its `name` is very much unsafe (in the Rust sense), as it relies entirely on some knowledge the programmer has about the runtime state that is unavailable to the compiler?  Is that what you mean when you refer to "*direct data access*" in C++?

Comment: @eggyal I believe the point isn't how to access `name` (which only `Named` instances will have) but rather how to access `children` (which all `Node` instances are supposed to have).

Comment: @eggyal Yep, with this data layout pretty much you can't (Well, in C++ you can perform a dynamic_cast<T> if you have RTTI enabled, and check if the cast was successful). In the other hand, I could store a string for example, in order to differentiate the types.
By _"direct data access"_ I meant like just reading the field (Sorry, I've made up the term), in cases where you know the type (Outside the tree structure, like in an update list or in creation time), instead of though a getter or something alike.

Comment: @DenysSéguret You mean something like this: `trait Leaf {}` and `struct Node { leaf: Leaf }`?
That could work out, I didn't think of that possibility.

Comment: @SigmaSoldier yes (with node being (simplified) `struct Node<Leaf> { leaf: Leaf, children: Vec<Node<Leaf>> }`)

Comment: I suppose my point was that this C++ polymorphism is fundamentally unsafe, and can only be directly replicated in Rust with `unsafe` code.  (You can do something like `dynamic_cast` with `<dyn Any>::downcast_ref`, or if you're tagging the types with an identifier like a string then you could just use an `enum`).  Once you've solved that problem, it should be straightforward to directly access `children`.

Comment: @DenysSéguret except that this kind of generic implies that all children have the same `Leaf` type as the parent.

Comment: @eggyal C++ guarantees that descendant classes start with the same layout as their ancestors. So given a pointer to an instance of `Named`, you can be sure that the `children` field is at the same place as for any other type of `Node`. This is perfectly safe but can't be replicated in Rust. The closest we could come is `struct Node { leaf: Box<dyn Leaf>, children: Vec<Node> };` but this adds an extra indirection.

Comment: @Jmb: what extra indirection?  `children` can still be accessed directly in your Rust example.  Sure, there’s indirection in accessing `leaf` but that was exactly my point: any attempt to do that in C++ must either be unsafe (replicable with `unsafe` Rust) or must involve similar indirection.

Comment: In C++ there is no indirection when accessing `name` from a pointer to a `Named` instance and no unsafety either. There is unsafety in casting a pointer to a `Node` into a pointer to a `Named`, but once you have the `Named` (for ex. before you insert it in the tree or as the `this` parameter to one of its methods) then accessing `name` is straightforward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only want to use `dyn` when you want the ability to mix and match implementations of `TreeLike`, but you don't seem to based on the C++ example.

You want to reference `Self` instead of `dyn TreeLike`:

```
trait TreeLike {
    fn get_children(&mut self) -> &mut Vec<Rc<RefCell<Self>>>;
}
```

Used like so:

```
struct A {
    children: Vec<Rc<RefCell<A>>>, // Note how I'm referencing the actual type here
}

impl TreeLike for A {
    fn get_children(&mut self) -> &mut Vec<Rc<RefCell<Self>>> {
        &mut self.children // and that it's fine to return here as here Self == A
    }
}
```